# Passing a value from cmd/runtime using gradle is not getting picked up

Tags: java, gradle

I have an abstract class that has a value of `workingDirectory` (variable)
I extended this in a new class (BaseClass). I want to override this by providing a value at runtime, and this is not happening. It is taking the default value.

I am using Gradle to run that file, it has test cases

The command in the code (BaseClass)

```
private static final String workingDirectory = System.getenv("infrastructurePath")==null?"./infrastructure":System.getenv("infrastructurePath");
```

The command I used to run from cmd

```
.\gradlew --info :testModule:testInfrastructure -DinfrastructurePath='./infrastructure-localtests'
```

But, it is taking `./infrastructure` every time and not `./infrastructure-localtests` when I try to pass the value from the command prompt. Where do I make the change?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar situation long back. I was using IntelliJ for the same.
Try making the following changes:

1. In your base class, change the name of your `workingDirectory` variable. It should not be the same as you have in the abstract class.
2. Use the new variable name everywhere.
3. Use `System.getproperty("name of the path / or path variable");`
   Do not use `System.getenv()` with a ternary operator. It didn't work for me.
4. Now, go to your `build.gradle`.
5. As you told you are running the test cases. you would be having a task created in `tasks.register('YourTestName', Test)`
6. Inside that, add a new line of

   systemProperty "YourPath", System.getProperty("YourPath", "./TheDefaultPathIfNoConditionMatches");

Now, at run time, if you simply run the tests, the control will go to the default path. If you want it to go to a new path, add an -D argument like this

```
-DinfrastructurePath="./WhateverPath"
```

This should work for you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have changed a bit of my problem statement. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Seen, it doesn't change anything. This should work for you or at least put you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I made a few changes in your answer and it worked perfectly. Much appreciated.